# get twitter following list with mechanize

Tags: html, python-3.x, redirect, twitter, mechanize

hi I'm trying to get twitter following list with this code:

```
import mechanize

u = "https://mobile.twitter.com/login"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open(u)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br["session[username_or_email]"] = 'myusername'
br["session[password]"] = 'password'
br.submit() 

u = "https://twitter.com/myusername/following"
br.open(u)
h = (br.response().read())
h= h.decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")
print(h)
```

but I don't receive response i expect, this is the response:

```
<body>
<noscript>
<center>
If you’re not redirected soon, please <a href="/myusername/">use this link</a>.
</center>
</noscript>
<script nonce="bVaerlhg3shgP1zVFxg==">
document.cookie = "app_shell_visited=1;path=/;max-age=5";    location.replace(location.href.split("#")[0]);
</script>
</body>
```

why browser dos not go to the followings page?

Comment: you could just use the twitter API instead of trying to scrape it from the web. `https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-list`

Comment: Scraping the Twitter website is against the Terms of Sevice.